# Which loss function should I use if my data is multi-label and my target vectors are not one-hot encoded?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, multilabel-classification, cross-entropy

I just read through this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-entropy-for-classification-d98e7f974451) that explains the difference between binary cross-entropy and categorical cross-entropy, and in particular, I had a question about this picture:

[image]

The author addressed the multi-label case where your target (or ground truth) labels are one-hot encoded, but what loss function would you use if your target labels were not one-hot encoded? For example, if only half of the panda was in the image, and I then labeled the image as [1, 0, 0.5], would I still use binary-cross entropy in this case? How does the math work out for cases where the target vector is not binary?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the article you are referring to has mentioned that cross-entropy works for all cases as long as you have two probability vectors. One for the target and one for the predicted.

> if only half of the panda was in the image, and I then labeled the image as [1, 0, 0.5], would I still use binary-cross entropy in this case?

Answer: No, you would be using multi-label cross entropy here as there is presence of multiple labels in the same image. This target probability vector can be converted to one-hot encoded vector. It will look like [1,0,1]. 0.5 is converted to 1 because object with that label is present in the image. For calculation you can refer to the article where he explains multi-label classification where he says:

> Our target can represent multiple (or even zero) classes at once. We compute the binary cross-entropy for each class separately and then sum them up for the complete loss.